# Google Colab: Why matplotlib has a behaviour different then default after importing pandas_profiling?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, google-colaboratory, pandas-profiling

When using a notebook in Google Colab, my *matplotlib* plots have different behaviors whether I import the library [pandas-profiling](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling) or not.

If I do not import *pandas-profiling*, the plots are displayed **inline by default**. But if I import the library, the plots **stop being displayed inline**.

## Workarounds (possible solutions)

- Updating the *pandas-profiling* library before importing it resolves the problem.
- Adding `%matplotlib inline` **after** importing *pandas-profiling* resolves the problem.

## Reproducing

Run this code in Google Colab to reproduce the problem. Test it with and without importing *pandas_profiling*. For each test, **you will need to terminate the session** (Runtime->Manage Sessions->Terminate). Just restarting the runtime is not enough.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# importing the pandas_profiling makes matplotlib
# to stop showing the plot inline
# import pandas_profiling
plt.plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
```

The [expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmsKw.png) is to show the plot inline by default, but after importing *pandas-profiling*, the plots [stop being displayed inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEGl3.png).

## The real problem

I stumbled upon this problem when my *seaborn* plotting functions started to break.

For example, consider the following code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import pandas_profiling
import seaborn as sns

def plot():
    ax = sns.pointplot([1, 2], [1, 2])
    print(len(ax.collections))
```

Now call `plot()` in two different jupyter cells.

- Without *pandas-profiling*: each function call will print 1.
- With *pandas-profiling*: each function call will add 1 to the previous output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the version of `pandas_profiling` that is installed by default in Google Colab. The installed version (1.4.1) used to change the *matplotlib*'s backend to `agg` when imported. The default *matplotlib*'s backend in Colab is `module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline`.

We can see that by running the following before and after importing *pandas-profiling*:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

This behavior was changed in pull-request [#125](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/pull/125), which stops changing *matplotlib*'s backend.

Until Google Colab updates the installed version, manually updating it seems to be the best solution. Just run the following in your Colab Notebook:

```sh
!pip install --upgrade pandas_profiling
```